# Get Value From Dynamic textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

In the given code i have create a dynamic textarea, now when i try to get insert value from that textarea. It gives me null value.

```
 <form name="myForm">
 <textarea name="fname" <%#!((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).Code.Equals("OTH", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "style='display: none;'" : string.Empty%> id="text<%#((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).ID%>" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter other item details"></textarea>
 </form>
```

Given is my function to get value from textarea box:

```
 function ValidateData() {
            if ($("textarea").is(":visible")) {
                //var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
                var x = document.getElementsByName("fname").value;
                if (x == null || x == "") {
                    alert("Please Enter Other Item Details");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else return true
        }
```

Comment: getElementsByName will get a list of elements, which don't have a value property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textarea was dynamic so you can used textarea change event. You can use given code on load, so whenever you input text it sets on OtherItemValue:

```
var OtherItemValue;
 $("textarea").on('input change keyup', function () {
                if (this.value.length) {
                    OtherItemValue = this.value;
                } else {
                    OtherItemValue = "";
                }
            });
```

And then you can used below code:

```
function ValidateData() {
    if ($("textarea").is(":visible")) {
 if (OtherItemValue == null || OtherItemValue == "") {
            alert("Please Enter Other Item Details");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myForm">
 <textarea name="fname" <%#!((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).Code.Equals("OTH", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "style='display: none;'" : string.Empty%> id="text<%#((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).ID%>" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter other item details"></textarea>
</form>
```

Your function should now look like this

```
function ValidateData() {
        if ($("textarea").is(":visible")) {
            //var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
            var x = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value;
            if (x == null || x == "") {
                alert("Please Enter Other Item Details");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else return true
    }
```

The problem with your code is that getElementsByName will get a list of elements, which don't have a value property. You need to get only a particular element and get its value. This solution may solve your problem, but will work if you don't have any other element with name as fname above the textarea.

Comment: textarea already have dynamic id, you can not define it two times.

Comment: @Developer check now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery already, why don't you use it to achieve the desired result?

Your code would look like this:

```
function ValidateData() {
    if ($("textarea").is(":visible")) {
        var x = $("textarea").val();
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("Please Enter Other Item Details");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

---

If you really need to use standard library, @Rachit Gupta's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39409355/951007) should solve the problem.

Comment: It is not Working

Comment: If the problem is "not getting ``true`` as a result", just remove ``else`` keyword - it's not necessary and forces your code to return ``undefined`` in some cases.

Comment: Problem is that whatever i insert in textarea it gives me null value @mdziekon

Comment: I've literally copied your HTML code, pasted it into the JSFiddle and fixed the script. **It works**, you can check it out on JSFiddle yourself), so the problem has to be somewhere else in your code (which you didn't show us).

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery .val() method to retrieve the value of the text area.
you need to initialise textarea to empty at document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("textarea[name='fname']").val("");    
});

    function ValidateData() {

    if ($("textarea").is(":visible")) {
        var x = $("textarea[name='fname']").val();
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("In if " + x);
            return false;
        }
        else {
              alert("In else" + x);
        }
    }
    else {
            return true
    }
}
```

Comment: it is Not Working @DPT